# Paper " Deep learning requires rethinking generalization"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was reading this paper [Understanding Deep learning requires rethinking generalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530) and I can't figure it out why does it say on page 5, under section 2.2 Implications, Redemacher complexity that the bound is trivial ?

> Since our randomiyation tests suggest that many neural networks fit the training set with random labels perfectly, we expect that Rad(H)=1 for the corresponding model class H. **This, of course, a trivial upper bound on the Rademacher complexity that does not lead to useful generalization bounds in realistic settings.**

Apparently I am missing some knowledge on Radmacher, since I can´t understand how do they come to this conclusion. I would be very thankful if someone could explain it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper the function `h` is bounded by 1 and therefore the Rademacher complexity is trivially bounded by 1 (you sum `n` terms equal to 1 and divide by `n`).

Comment: I will go step by step in order to check if I really understood

1)according to the paper, based on the research, all networks are able to train to 0 training error.
2) the Rademacher complexity is checking if they are able to fit a training set with random labels 
3) if yes then it gives 1, and since in all cases it will manage we have a sum of n*1 which is later divided by n.
4) we get a result 1
5) it it is convinced trivial because as you said in the paper the function is bounded by 1. And I can´t find this bound in the paper!?

Comment: yes that' it. `h` is bounded by 1 because it represents the probability of `x_i` to have label 1 (it is a common notation)